# When spring boot service starts, insert data into mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm currently new to the Spring Boot Java framework and I'm building a simple application. When my service starts, I want to be able to read a raw file from a URL, parse that data, and upload it into my mongodb database of atlas. So far this is what I have:

```
@Service
public class CoronaVirusDataService {
  private List<LocationStats> allConfirmedStats = new ArrayList<>();
  MongoOperations mongoOperations;

  @PostConstruct // run this method as soon as the application runs
  @Scheduled(cron = "* * 1 * * *") // execute this method every day
  public void fetchVirusData() {
    List<LocationStats> newStats = new ArrayList<>(); // to hold the stats of each state
    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    // creating a new http request
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(ConstantsUtil.VIRUS_CONFIRMED_DATA_URL))
        .build();

    // get a response by having the client send the request
    try {
      HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
      // parse the body of the request from csv format to readable format
      StringReader csvBodyReader = new StringReader(httpResponse.body());
      Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(csvBodyReader);
      for (CSVRecord record: records) {
        // create a model with the parsed data
        LocationStats stats = new LocationStats();
        stats.setState(record.get("Province/State"));
        stats.setCountry(record.get("Country/Region"));
        // the latest day
        int latestCases = Integer.parseInt(record.get(record.size() - 1));
        int prevDayCases = Integer.parseInt(record.get(record.size() - 2));
        stats.setLatestTotalCases(latestCases);
        stats.setDiffFromPreviousDay(prevDayCases);

        mongoOperations.save(LocationStats);

        // add to new stats
        newStats.add(stats);
      }
      // assign to class array -> we use this array to display the data
      this.allConfirmedStats = newStats;

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

So the main issue with this is the data is not saving to the mongoDB once I call mongoOperations.save(). Also, I've learned that it is bad practice to maintain some type of state in a Service. What is the best practice for this? Will inserting the data into MongoDB take care of that since we are not managing state.

Here is my model class that I want to save to mongodb

```
@Document(collection = "LocationStats")
public class LocationStats {
  /** Location model to show corona virus statistics in each state*/
  @Id
  private String state;
  private String country;
  private int latestTotalCases;
  private int diffFromPreviousDay;

  public String getState() {
    return state;
  }

  public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
  }

  public int getLatestTotalCases() {
    return latestTotalCases;
  }

  public void setLatestTotalCases(int latestTotalCases) {
    this.latestTotalCases = latestTotalCases;
  }

  public int getDiffFromPreviousDay() {
    return diffFromPreviousDay;
  }

  public void setDiffFromPreviousDay(int diffFromPreviousDay) {
    this.diffFromPreviousDay = diffFromPreviousDay;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "LocationStats{" +
        "state='" + state + '\'' +
        ", country='" + country + '\'' +
        ", latestTotalCases=" + latestTotalCases +
        '}';
  }
}
```

once I have my models saved into mongoDB, I want to read from the database and get all the data from each collection and display it on the webpage. I'm thinking I'd fetch that data within the controller class and pass it to the frontend, is this good practice? here is my controller class.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  /** Controller class to generate/render the html UI */
  @Autowired
  CoronaVirusDataService coronaVirusDataService;

  @Autowired
  MongoOperations mongoOperations;

  @GetMapping("/") // map this to the root template
  public String home(Model model) {
    List<LocationStats> allStats = coronaVirusDataService.getAllConfirmedStats();

    // instead of above getter method, have a method call that fetches all data from mongoDB and return it as a List<LocationStats>

    // get the total confirmed cases
    int totalConfirmedCases = allStats.stream().mapToInt(LocationStats::getLatestTotalCases).sum();
    int totalNewCases = allStats.stream().mapToInt(LocationStats::getDiffFromPreviousDay).sum();


    // send the models to the view
    model.addAttribute("locationStats", allStats);
    model.addAttribute("totalReportedCases", totalConfirmedCases);
    model.addAttribute("totalNewCases", totalNewCases);

    return "home";
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `CommandLineRunner`, which can be used for one-shot tasks to run at startup. (And use constructor injection instead of field injection; it'll save you headaches down the line!)

Comment: it's hard to tell why it's not saving. maybe you have several mongodb's installed and checking the wrong one?

Comment: thanks for both of your feeback. I'm currently using MongoDB Atlas. Could that be it? I was facing this issue of "No SNI name"